# Fetching rows in Php MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to increment $x in this function to get next record in table. But it is incrementing only once . Any Help is appreciated

This is the function I call,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getnextques(){
        document.getElementById("quescontent").innerHTML= '<?php
        $x++;
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_content WHERE id=".$x) or die(mysql_error());  
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            echo $row['ques'] ;
        }; 
        ?>'
}
</script>
```

from ,

```
<a href="javascript:getnextques()" class="startbutton" id="mediumone"> Next </a>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot mix like that `Javascript` with `PHP`. PHP is server side based, javascript is browser based.

You should use Ajax for that (`jQuery`)

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 0;
function getnextques(){
    var newX = x++;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'script.php',
        data: { x: newX },
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("quescontent").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

and `script.php`

```
<?php
    // mysql connection
    $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_content WHERE id=".$x) or die(mysql_error());  
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo $row['ques'] ;
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php code runs on the server and will be statically returned to the browser, where the javascript runs. You need to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in order to dynamically fetch content.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not familiar with Ajax, or could not use it for any reason, take the user to next page to show the next question.